# Formatting LaTEX equations

Tags: equations, formatting

I am trying to input some equations in my latex document, the first equation is fine, and the first equation number is shown on the side but for the second equation, the equation number is out of place as shown in the provided picture. I believe it is a formatting issue, any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}



\begin{document}





\begin{equation}
PL_{LoS} = 20{\log}d + 20{\log}f + 20{\log}(\frac{4{\pi}}{c}) + \eta_{LoS}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
PL_{NLoS} = \underbrace{20{\log}d + 20{\log}f + 20{\log}(\frac{4{\pi}} 
{c})}_\textrm{FSPL} + \underbrace{\eta_{NLoS}}_{\textrm{{\eta}{\xi}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: My output]

Comment: please try to make more reasonable examples, do you need `forest` package to show the problem?

Comment: Never ignore errors, if you get an error ask about the error message (`! Missing $ inserted.` here) any pdf produced after an error is not intended to be usable.

Comment: ok, thanks will try to get the errors sorted first

Comment: The forest package is for another part of my document, I included all the packages I used to make sure that there are no mistakes with the packages I have in my document.

Comment: please don't do that, it makes it harder for people to trace what tex is doing and answer your question, you can easily tell before posting that none of the packages listed are related to the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the 18 [!] packages that are loaded in the OP's code are needed to typeset the equations. Worse, some of those packages are mutually incompatible, such as the `cite` and `natbib` packages.  The *only* package that's really needed here is `amsmath` -- which, oddly, isn't among the 18 selected by the OP.

Please rid yourself of the dreadful habit of encasing all instances of `\log` in curly braces. It's not only unnecessary, it's actually counterproductive as it badly messes up the spacing. Please also consider replacing `(\frac{4{\pi}}{c})` with `(4\pi/c)` -- please no curly braces around `\pi` (or `\xi`!) either -- for the two equations at hand.

Last but not least, here's a suggestion already made by David Carlisle: Do replace `{\textrm{{\eta}{\xi}}` with `{\eta\xi}`. Aside: Why would you want to render the math-mode-only symbols `\eta` and `\xi` in text mode?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % only package needed here

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
PL_{\mathrm{LoS}}  &= 20\log d + 20\log f + 20\log(4\pi/c) + \eta_{\mathrm{LoS}} \\
PL_{\mathrm{NLoS}} &= {\underbrace{20\log d + 20\log f + 20\log(4\pi/c)}_{\mathrm{FSPL}}} 
                     + \underbrace{\eta_{\mathrm{NLoS}}}_{\eta\xi}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your document produces

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.37 ...erbrace{\eta_{NLoS}}_{\textrm{{\eta}{\xi}}
                                                  }
?
```

(no pdf after an error is usable)

`\textrm` makes a box with nested *text* so does not allow math commands like `\eta`

Just use

```
_{\eta\xi}
```

not

```
_{\textrm{{\eta}{\xi}}
```